# Is there a way to store in a PHP array the selected <option> from a HTML <select>?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

My idea is to store in a PHP array the selected `<option>` from different html `<select>` ' s.

**In a form I generate using a php function called from a Jquery function a `<ul>` containing each list element text and a `<select>`**

Like so:

### Part of the form where the list elements are added:

```html
<div>
    <label for="lineasP" id="asignarBdto" hidden>Productos de este pedido:</label>
</div>
<div>
    <ul id="lineaPedidos" hidden>
        <!-- Added here -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

---

### JQuery function that calls the PHP function:

```js
$("#pedidos").on("input", function() {
    $.get("cambio_cliente.php", { idPedido: $("#pedidos").val()}, function (data) {
        $("#lineaPedidos").empty();
        $("#lineaPedidos").append(data);

        $("#asignarBdto").show();
        $("#lineaPedidos").show();
    });
});
```

---

### PHP function:

```php
// Si llegamos a este script por haber seleccionado un pedido
if(isset($_GET["idPedido"])){
    // Abrimos una conexión con la BD y consultamos la lista de productos dado un pedido
    $conexion = crearConexionBD();
    $resultado = listarProductos($conexion, $_GET["idPedido"]);

    if($resultado != NULL){
        // Para cada producto del listado devuelto
        foreach($resultado as $lineaPedido) {
            //Listamos los productos de cada pedido
            echo "<li>" . $lineaPedido["NUM_LINEA_P"] .": cantidad= ". $lineaPedido["CANTIDAD"] .", importe= ". $lineaPedido["IMPORTE"] ." <br><label>Base de dto: </label><select class=\"linPed\" required><option value=\"\" hidden disabled selected>% DTO</option> <option value=\"21\">21%</option> <option value=\"16\">16%</option> <option value=\"8\">8%</option></select></li>";
        }
    }
    // Cerramos la conexión y borramos de la sesión la variable "idPedido"
    cerrarConexionBD($conexion);
    unset($_GET["idPedido"]);
}
```

---

So far so good.

The form display this fields without problems:

[image: form alta factura]

---

## The problem starts here

I need to store each selected `<option>` into the array I mentioned in the very begining. I don't know how many `<select>` ' s will be created, so I can't create id's for each of them. I decided to create a class (linPed) for this selects, and tried this JS function:

```js
$(".linPed").on("input", function(){
   alert("all good");
});
```

I first tried do some 'logging' to see if the function executes correctly, but doesn't show the alert.
**Despite of that, even if the function executed correctly, how do I add in the array the selected `.linPed` value? Or maybe there is an easier way to do it?**

---

## EDIT 1:

```js
alert("hello");
    $("select.linPed").on("change", function(){
       alert("this works"); 
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul>
    <div>
        <li>
            Hello
        </li>
        <select class="linPed">
            <option value="21">
                21%
            </option>
            <option value="16">
                16%
            </option>
            <option value="8">
                8%
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
   <div>
        <li>
            bye
        </li>
        <select class="linPed">
            <option value="21">
                21%
            </option>
            <option value="16">
                16%
            </option>
            <option value="8">
                8%
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</ul>
<select class="linPed">
            <option value="21">
                21%
            </option>
            <option value="16">
                16%
            </option>
            <option value="8">
                8%
            </option>
</select>
```

I have created an snippet testing if the problem was that the `<select>` 's were inside the `<li>`.

---

## EDIT 2:

I still don't know why, but if I try to acces the `<option>` 's value from a separated script, doesn't work. I tried adding an `onchange` field to the `<select>`'s and finally works.

Comment: @cbroe If you read the question before the edit, on the PHP function part, you can see that as inner html of the LI there is a `<select>`. The div as a child of ul is just a test, not the code I try to solve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personaly I would use `change` in stead of `input` in the `.on()` function for detecting a change like:

```js
$('.linPed').on('change', function() {
  alert( this.value );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select class='linPed'>
    <option value="1"><li>One</li></option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
</select>
```

For getting al the value I would use the `.each()` function like:

```
var arr = [];
$('.linPed').each(function(){
  arr.push($(this).val())
})
```

If I'm correct this gives you al the selected values in the array `arr`.

**Edit:**

I executed `echo` myself and lookt at it. It is there where lays the problem. Your class is't `linPed` it's `\"linPed"\`.

[image]

In your code replece al the `\` with nothing.

**Edit 2:**

Having a look at your snippet and saw it instantly. You `js` ran before the `html` is loaded. Put your `JavaScript` at the end of your code. Or put an ready function around your code like

```
$(function () {
  //Code ..
});
```

Comment: onchange doesn't work neither, and the `arr` is a js var, how do I store its value into the php array?

Comment: That's weird indeed. However for passing the `arr` vat to your php file take a lookat this qestion: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917576/how-do-i-pass-javascript-variables-to-php . you can select the best option for your code.

Comment: For the `change` part i made an snippet with simple code end it works perfect!

Comment: Could the `<li>` affect to the `<select>`?

Comment: @JesúsDíazCastro made one with an `<li>` still works. Are you sure your `linPed` class is on the `<select>` and not on the childeren?

Comment: I think so, in the question is shown on the PHP function part

Comment: Made an eddit to my answer please look at it

Comment: I have just tried that, but still doesnt show the alert box. I have edited the question, with the class name withouth errors. and still doesn't work...

Comment: Edit wil do it!

Answer (score 0):

**Despite the fact I wouldn't have achieved the solution without Tim's answer, I want to post how have I stored the html values into the php array in case someone ecounters this same problem.**

Using `onchange` inside the `<select>` field I call a js function (with parameters: the value of the selected option and the select id)

```html
<select onchange="añadirDTO(this.value, this.id)">
   ...
</select>
```

---

## JS

First of all, create 2 global variables that correspond to the parameters of the function, in this case array and number.

```js
var dtoSeleccionados = [];
var id = 0; //Initialize both var
```

Now the function that receives the data:

This function will be called each time the user changes a select, so to avoid useless values an store only the final decision of each select, check if the id of the select passed as parameter is equal to the global id var. If it isn't we change the global id for the new id, else change the last element of the global array

```js
function añadirDTO(baseDTO, linId){
    if(linId !== id){
        id = linId;
        dtoSeleccionados.push(baseDTO);
    }else{
        dtoSeleccionados[dtoSeleccionados.length - 1] = baseDTO;
    }
}
```

Once the user has completed the form and the array values are definitives, using an auxiliar `<select multiple>` field that is hidden, we modify its inner html like so:

```html
<div>
    <!-- we use a label to identify the element that it corresponds with the php var -->
    <label for="baseDTO" hidden></label>
    <!-- the name of the select must match with the php array name with '[]' at the end -->
    <select multiple name="baseDTO[]" id="baseDTO" hidden>

    </select>
</div>
```

```js
function seleccionarTodo(){
    text="";
    for(i=0; i<dtoSeleccionados.length; i++){
        text += "<option selected value=\""+dtoSeleccionados[i]+"\"></option>\n";
    }

    document.getElementById("baseDTO").innerHTML = text;
}
```

The above function goes at the submit of the form like so:

```html
<input type="submit" onclick="seleccionarTodo()" value="Registrar factura"/>
```

And that succesfully add one by one different `<select> <option>` 's into an array